# generate a random password and update the database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have to update the passwords for all of the existing users with random unique password. I have about 4000 users using SQL SERVER.

My code is

```
$userSQL = "SELECT a002UserID FROM tbl002password WHERE a002UserID LIKE 'non%'";
$userrs  = $db->query($userSQL);
$userList1 = array();
while($row = $userrs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $userList1[] = $row->a002UserID;
}
foreach($userList1 as $uid){
    function generatePassword ($length = 8)
    {
        $password = '';
        $chars = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0, 9));
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
            $password .= $chars[array_rand($chars)];
        }
        return $password;
    }

    $pass_gen = generate_password();
    $insertPass = "UPDATE tbl002password SET a002password = '$pass_gen' WHERE a002UserID = '$uid'";
    $db->exec($insertPass);
    echo "updated $uid";
}
```

If remove the 'for' loop

- When I run the query for only one user then it runs fine.
- the same password is assign to all when select all user.

Comment: Looks prone to race conditions because you select first and then update.. Besides it also looks prone to SQL injections. if this code is not accessible to the outside world and only one user is running this forgot what i said.. At first seight you need to place the function `generatePassword()` outside the loop.

Comment: dont store plain text passwords, hash them.

Comment: I did place the function out side the loop but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// 1. Don't declare functions inside loops. Functions should generally only ever be declared
//    in either the global scope, or a class definition.
function generatePassword ($length = 8) {
    $password = '';
    $chars = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0, 9));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $password .= $chars[array_rand($chars)];
    }
    return $password;
} 

$userSQL = "SELECT a002UserID FROM tbl002password WHERE a002UserID LIKE 'non%'";
$userrs  = $db->query($userSQL);

$userList1 = array();
while($row = $userrs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $userList1[] = $row->a002UserID;
}

// 2. Preparing statements like this increase performance as they are only parsed _once_,
//    but executed many times.
$insertPass = $db->prepare("UPDATE tbl002password SET a002password = ? WHERE a002UserID = ?");
foreach($userList1 as $uid) {
    $pass_gen = generate_password();
    $insertPass->execute([$pass_gen, $uid]);
    echo "updated $uid";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why loop through the 4,000 rows?

I'd apply a single update

**Example**

```
Declare @tbl002password  table (a002UserID  varchar(50),a002password varchar(50))
Insert Into @tbl002password values
 ('JS1234'   ,'Password1')
,('nonTI5656','Password2')
,('nonSC5657','Password3')

Update @tbl002password set a002password=right(NewID(),3)+left(abs(convert(bigint,HashBytes('MD5', a002UserID))),5)
 Where a002UserID like 'non%'


Select *
 From  @tbl002password
```

**The Updated Table**

```
a002UserID  a002password
JS1234      Password1
nonTI5656   FED25902
nonSC5657   3C815639
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just run this in a sandbox:

```
$userList1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

function generatePassword ($length = 8)
    {
        $password = '';
        $chars = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0, 9));
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
            $password .= $chars[array_rand($chars)];
    }
    return $password;
}; 


foreach($userList1 as $uid){
    $pass_gen = generatePassword();

    echo $pass_gen . '   ';
}
```

The result is this:

```
ve6XzQzA   cL93fvVH   GtdP3LP3   8rKDRGJ2   qjt9j6Rv
```

Which looks fine to me. There is one obvious syntax error in your code. You call "generate_password();" while the function is actually called "generatePassword". I agree to the points Raymond Nijland made regarding your SQL. I would recommend you change this as well.